# Why doesn't PyRun_String evaluate bool literals?

Tags: python, boolean, cpython

I need to evaluate a Python expression from C++. This code seems to work:

```
PyObject * dict = PyDict_New();
PyObject * val = PyRun_String(expression, Py_eval_input, dict, 0);
Py_DECREF(dict);
```

Unfortunately, it fails horribly if expression is "True" of "False" (that is, val is 0 and PyErr_Occurred() returns true). What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't they evaluate to Py_True and Py_False respectively?

Comment: what does PyErr_Print() show when you call it after the failure?

Comment: I know, I should have done this before, but I can't call PyErr_Print() in my application for a number of reasons. Anyway, I reproduced this in an isolated file, and this is what I got:
NameError: name 'False' is not defined
!! It looks like this literal is not available from C... !

Comment: Since that answers your question you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
PyObject* PyRun_String(const char *str, int start, PyObject *globals, PyObject *locals);
```

If you want True and False they will have to be in the `*globals` dict passed to the interpreter. You might be able to fix that by calling `PyEval_GetBuiltins`.

From the Python 2.6 source code:

```
if (PyDict_GetItemString(globals, "__builtins__") == NULL) {
    if (PyDict_SetItemString(globals, "__builtins__",
                 PyEval_GetBuiltins()) != 0)
        return NULL;
}
```

If that doesn't work, you could try to `PyRun_String("import __builtin__ as __builtins__", globals, locals)` before calling `PyRun_String("True", ...)`.

You might notice the Python interactive interpreter always runs code in the `__main__` module which we haven't bothered to create here. I don't know whether you need to have a `__main__` module, except that there are a lot of scripts that contain `if __name__ == "__main__"`.

Comment: wow, I never realized that True, False and even None are part of the __builtin__ module... the first solution did it for me, thank you for pointing me in the right direction! I found some more info here: http://www.python.org/doc/2.3/whatsnew/section-bool.html